# Is my code efficient for finding out the next palindrome given a positive integer?

Tags: c#, arrays, palindrome

Problem statement: For a given positive number, I have to find out the immediately next palindrome. Eg:

```
For 808, output:818
2133, output:2222
```

I want to know if my code is efficient at all, and how efficient is it? Is this a good way to solve the problem?

Logic explanation: I've set `i` to the leftmost position of the number, `j` to the rightmost position an I'm basically comparing the 2 numbers. I assign `num[j]=num[i]` always, and keep track if the number becomes greater than the original value, or lesser, or equal. In the end,that is: `j-i==1 or j==i`, depending on number of digits of the number being even or odd, I see if the number became greater or not, taking a decision accordingly.

EDIT: The number can be upto 100,000 digits long!..That was part of the problem statement,so I'm trying to avoid brute force methods.

```
int LeftNineIndex = 0, RightNineIndex = 0;
bool NumberLesser = false, NumberGreater = false;
string number = Console.ReadLine();
char[] num = number.ToCharArray();
int i, j, x, y;
for (i = 0, j = num.Length - 1; i <= j; i++, j--)
{
      char m;
      Int32.TryParse(num[i].ToString(),out x);
      Int32.TryParse(num[j].ToString(), out y);
      if (x > y)
      {
           NumberGreater = true;
           NumberLesser = false;
      }
      else if (x < y)
      {
           if (j - i == 1)
           {
                NumberGreater = true;
                NumberLesser = false;
                x = x + 1;
                Char.TryParse(x.ToString(), out m);
                num[i] = m;
           }
           else
           {
                NumberGreater = false;
                NumberLesser = true;
           }             
     }

     if ((j == i && NumberGreater == false) || (j - i == 1 && x == y &&  NumberGreater == false))
     {
           if (x != 9)  // if the number is 9, then i can't add 1 to it
           {
                x = x + 1;
                Char.TryParse(x.ToString(), out m);
                num[i] = m;
           }
           else
           {
                if (num.Length != 1)
                {
                    Int32.TryParse(num[LeftNineIndex].ToString(), out x);
                    Int32.TryParse(num[RightNineIndex].ToString(), out y);
                    x = x + 1;
                    Char.TryParse(x.ToString(), out m);
                    num[LeftNineIndex] = m;
                    num[RightNineIndex] = m;
                }
                else
                {
                    // user has entered just '9', in which case I've hard-coded
                    Console.WriteLine("11");
                }
           }
     }
     num[j] = num[i];
     if (x != 9)  //gives us the index of the number closest to the middle, which is not 9
     {
          LeftNineIndex = i;
          RightNineIndex = j;
     }
}
Console.WriteLine(num);
```

Comment: So is this a homework question?

Comment: Nope...just a programming puzzle I read at some website

Comment: All palindromes with an even number of digits are divisible by 11. Neat fact and possibly useful shortcut. Eg 2222 / 11 = 202

Comment: @BeRecursive: So, I'll have to check if it's an even digit number, then keep on incrementing it and dividing it by 11?..Is that the way?

Comment: Your current code looks overly complicated to me. `BigInteger` together with a few high level functions, such as Linq's `Reverse` can lead to much shorter, and easier to understand code. On the other hand, converting from decimal is pretty expensive, so `BigInteger` based code is probably quite slow, compared to `char` based code.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: Thanks! for the algorithm as well as code review! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's relatively simple to find the next palindrome in constant time:

- Split the input in two halves (first half larger if length is odd)
- Now for the next palindrome there are two candidates:

  1. Keep the first half, and fix the second half
  2. Increment the first half by 1, and fix the second half
- Choose the first candidate if it is larger than the input, choose the second candidate otherwise.

The [`BigInteger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx) type is useful for implementing this:

This approach has a cost linear in the length of the input, i.e. it's logarithmic in the size of the number.

```
public static BigInteger NextPalindrome(BigInteger input)
{
    string firstHalf=input.ToString().Substring(0,(input.ToString().Length+1)/2);
    string incrementedFirstHalf=(BigInteger.Parse(firstHalf)+1).ToString();
    var candidates=new List<string>();
    candidates.Add(firstHalf+new String(firstHalf.Reverse().ToArray()));
    candidates.Add(firstHalf+new String(firstHalf.Reverse().Skip(1).ToArray()));
    candidates.Add(incrementedFirstHalf+new String(incrementedFirstHalf.Reverse().ToArray()));
    candidates.Add(incrementedFirstHalf+new String(incrementedFirstHalf.Reverse().Skip(1).ToArray()));
    candidates.Add("1"+new String('0',input.ToString().Length-1)+"1");
    return candidates.Select(s=>BigInteger.Parse(s))
              .Where(i=>i>input)
              .OrderBy(i=>i)
              .First();
}
```

Tested to work with all positive integers below 100000 by comparing with the native implementation.

The fifth case is easy to miss. If the number consists of all `9`s, incrementing the first half changes the length, and requires extra handling if the current length is odd (`9`, `999`,...).

Comment: That's similar to what I've done! :) ..Can you please tell me if it's good code?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it.  Seems to work.

```
        private int FindNextPaladindrone(int value)
    {
        int result = 0;
        bool found = false;

        while (!found)
        {
            value++;
            found = IsPalindrone(value);
            if (found)
                result = value;
        }

        return result;
    }

    private bool IsPalindrone(int number)
    {
        string numberString = number.ToString();
        int backIndex;

        bool same = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < numberString.Length; i++)
        {
            backIndex = numberString.Length - (i + 1);
            if (i == backIndex || backIndex < i)
                break;
            else
            {
                if (numberString[i] != numberString[backIndex])
                {
                    same = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return same;
    }
```

Comment: not all code paths return a value in your is palindrome method

you need a                 return same; outside your for loop

Comment: something happened when I pasted the code.  It ran fine when I tested it :)

Comment: must be those damn clipboard goblins again ;)